# Regular expressions: does not contain

Tags: php, regex

I know this question has been asked many times on SO, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find matches for any Facebook URL, **but not** when the URL contains "plugins/like" (as in "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like")

I've come out with the following, and I'm not quite sure why it is not working:

```
https?://(www)?\.facebook\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/((?!plugins/like).)
```

Am I making a very obvious mistake? Sorry if it doesn't make sense at all, but I've only trying a hand at PHP for the past five months.

Thank you very much for your time and your help.

**Edit:**
I'm getting matches for any FB URL so far, but it isn't excluding anything that contains plugins/like

Comment: Try moving the first `\.` into the `(www)?` block; If it's after it, it will match `http://.facebook.com` - which, if you're testing with a sample url of `http://facebook.com` it will fail.

Comment: Have you looked at facebook.co.uk Dave?

Comment: Try `!https?\://(www\.)?facebook\.[a-z]{2,4}/((?!plugins/like).*)!i`

Comment: @Pete I just did. I am so surprised the haven't got that TLD.

Comment: @DaveRandom As cybersquatting goes, it's not a very good job, is it?

Comment: @Pete Really not, no. Still I can live with having to use facebook.com, I was *seriously* dismayed when the reg on viper-7.com expired on Saturday, luckily it seems to have been restored before any of the squatters noticed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.facebook.com/',
    'https://facebook.com/plugins/foo',
    'http://facebook.ru/plugins/like',
);

$pattern = '#^https?://(www\.)?facebook\.[a-z]{2,4}/(?!plugins/like)#';

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo preg_match($pattern, $url) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Okay?

Comment: I thought it might be that last capture group screwing with it, but since it's there I imagine the OP wants to capture the path portion. Although [this](http://viper-7.com/eJRrjf) will sort that part out and the leading slash can be trimmed if necessary.

Comment: @AKG "Original Poster" or variations on that theme. I've seen a couple of other interpretations but they all mean basically that.

Comment: Orange Peel was the only thing I could come up with :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using `strpos()`

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/test/plugins/like?somestuff';

$matches = array();

if(preg_match('#^https?://(?:www)?\.facebook\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/(.*)$#', $url, $matches)
   && strpos($matches[1], "plugins/like") === false) {
  // ok
} else {
  // nope
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to esacpe special characters in the pattern. Characters like : and / must be following a backslash.

```
https?\:\/\/(www)?\.facebook\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\/((?!plugins\/like).)
```

Comment: `/` is not a special character in regexes and doesn't need to be escaped. Unless you use it as delimiter in PCRE, but why do so if you have saner choices?

Comment: It is in PHP, I just tested it (php is one of the tags in the question).

Comment: Forwardslashes need escaping?

Comment: I always use # as a delimiter for that very reason @Joey

Comment: As @Joey says, they need escaping only where they are ALSO used as the pattern delimiters. Forward slashes are not the only option for delimiters (there's also `#`, for example).

Comment: I'm still missing why `:` needs to be escaped.

Comment: @AKG The delimiter needs escaping, and Summoner seems to be assuming you are using `/` as a delimiter (which is a silly idea when matching URLs, I'd use `@` probably, `#` is also a URL meta character)

Comment: I just tested the code and that must be what he's doing wrong - It wouldn't work with a simple preg_match call.

Comment: Ok guys, I've tested it before actually. I can get matches from any FB URL so far, but somehow I can't get it to exclude any matches from plugins/like

Answer (score 0):

All is ok with your re (and it works; I've checked). The only thing I would change is write

```
(?!.*plugins/like)
```

instead of `(?!plugins/like).`. That is for cases when `plugins` goes not direct after the `facebook.com/`.